# Using javascript to load css file (by using @import not by link)

Tags: javascript, css, import

I have been trying to import a css file using @import through javascript.
I know there are other methods like createELement("link") through js but I need to import the css file instead of linking it, because I'm working on client site and their css is conflicting with mine. I can't set !important for all my css and thought @import css file has much higher preference than linked css file and its working.I just need to know how to import it using js.

Comment: Link the css in later than the conflicting css file. A terrible solution would be linking a css file that has that @import.

Comment: @Jashwant actually that terrible thing worked. linking the file which has the import statement is working. But is it a bad practice?

Comment: linking the higher preference file at the end of header also worked. Thanks @Jashwant

Answer (score 1):

Javascript does not have @import .You can check this link for more information
[More about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file)

Comment: Okay, so is there any other way to link css so that the main website's css wont get conflicted with mine.

Comment: you can take a look at specificity in css